# Material Design ripple only appearing on first HTML element

Tags: javascript, material-design, floating-action-button, material-components, material-components-web

I'm trying to implement [Material Design FABs](https://material.io/develop/web/components/buttons/floating-action-buttons) on the web with the ripple effect.

I have the following dummy HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bundle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="mdc-fab" id="first" aria-label="First">
            <div class="mdc-fab__ripple"></div>
        </button>
        <button class="mdc-fab" id="second" aria-label="Second">
            <div class="mdc-fab__ripple"></div>
        </button>
        <button class="mdc-fab" id="third" aria-label="Third">
            <div class="mdc-fab__ripple"></div>
        </button>
        <script src="bundle.js" async></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the SCSS:

```
@use "@material/fab/mdc-fab";
@use "@material/fab";
```

And here is the JS:

```
import {MDCRipple} from '@material/ripple';
const fabRipple = new MDCRipple(document.querySelector('.mdc-fab'));
```

I've got the ripple effect to show properly on the first button when clicked, but, for some reason, the ripple does not appear for any of the buttons that follow.

In other words, it seems the ripple effect is only working for the first element but not the ones after it. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I guess it helps to read the [documentation](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/importing-js) as well. ‍♂️

```
const fabRipple = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-fab'), function(el) {
    return new MDCRipple(el);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Docs for [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

> The [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) method `querySelector()` returns the first [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, `null` is returned.

If you want to select multiple elements, use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead.

But the `MDCRipple` constructor only seems to accept a single element. Hence, you could use a loop or [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to activate them all:

```
// Transform the NodeList to an Array using the ES6 spread syntax (...)
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-fab')]; 
const fabRipples = buttons.map(btn => new MDCRipple(btn)); // An Array of Ripple objects
```